# Warning a user when they press back button in an iframe in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, back, onbeforeunload

Is there a way to warn a user when they have made changes to a form and hit the back button, when the form is in an iframe? I have tried to use an event listener for `popstate`, and `beforeunload`. The `beforeunload` listener warns when a user tries to refresh, but not for pressing back. I have also tried adding `<Prompt/>` from `react-router-dom` v5 and that didn't work for me either.

Comment: If there is a trigger to open the iframe, you can use that trigger to keep a boolean state for when the iframe is open. If the user tries to unload the page when the state is `true`, you can then show the prompt.

Comment: The iframe only has a form on some pages though. I don't want to warn the user every time they are unloading the page, just when they are leaving the page with the form.